# jQuery sliding content and navigation active state

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, sliding

I have this jQuery code that is sliding content based on what links I click and I also have a hover effect for the links,

```
$("#nav a").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ paddingTop: "60px" }, 500);
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ paddingTop: "50px" }, 500);
});

var firstTime = true;
$("#nav a").click(function() {
    var divname = this.id;
    if (!firstTime) {
        if ($(".slid").hasClass(divname)) {
            firstTime = true;
            $(".slid").removeClass("slid").slideUp();
        } else {
            $(".slid").removeClass('slid').slideUp(500, function() {
                $("." + divname).slideToggle().addClass("slid");
            });
        }
    } else {
        $("." + divname).slideDown().addClass("slid");
        firstTime = false;
    }
});
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="ett">ett</a></li>
        <li><a id="tva">två</a></li>
        <li><a id="tre">tre</a></li>
        <li><a id="fyra">fyra</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So my question is, how would I add a active state to the links when I click them and then when I click them again it's goes away. And when I click a different link it switched the active state.

```
#nav li a.active {
    background-color: #242424;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

I would also have to prevent the animation on the active link so the padding doesn't go down to 50px but stays at 60px.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can use toggleClass("className")

Comment: toggleClass is not doing what I want it to.